# c# - How do I loop through a time range

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, for-loop

I would like to define the start time as 6pm and end time as 9pm. This time range (something looked like below) used for everyday's schedule. How do I implement in for loop? Appreciate for any reply.

```
6:00 PM 
6:30 PM 
7:00 PM 
7:30 PM 
8:00 PM 
8:30 PM 
9:00 PM
```

Comment: please show some source code... what have your tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: How is your time range defined?

Comment: And what about the date part, is that irrelevant?

Comment: @Lucero date is irrelevant since everyday using the same time range.

Comment: @Oded that is something I dun know. I know how to loop through a DATE range, but for my case, I just want the time only.

Comment: @Yahia I dun have any concept. here is the example of loop through date range. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847580/how-do-i-loop-through-a-date-range. However what I want is the loop through time only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could use while loop

```
var startTime = DateTime.Parse("2012-01-28 18:00:00");
var endTime = startTime.AddHours(3);
while (startTime <= endTime)
{
  System.Console.WriteLine(startTime.ToShortTimeString());
  startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(30);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple example with `TimeSpan`:

```
for (int minutes = 6 * 60; minutes <= 9 * 60; minutes += 30)
{
    Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes));
}
```

Comment: you may want to use `12+6` and `12+9` since the time is `PM` ;)

Comment: @Lucero Well, actually `TimeSpan` represents a **time interval**, not a date (i.e. the _quantity of time_ represented is not related to a specific day/hour). I'm not sure adding the notion of "after noon" is relevant for a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @key2k, I'm aware what a `TimeSpan` is. The point is that the timespan since midnight needs to be computed with the addition of 12 for PM, or you'll get AM times when adding it to a (pure) date.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using DateTime.Now.Hour to get the hour and use if clauses. see exemple below

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 9 && DateTime.Now.Hour <= 18) { Console.WriteLine("Bonjour " + Environment.UserName); }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Bonsoir " + Environment.UserName);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if u r going through current date with a time range from like 10:00:00 AM to 17:00:00 PM then u could use the below code

```
 DateTime startTime = DateTime.Parse("10:00:00");

    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Parse("17:00:00");
while (startTime <= endTime)
{
  System.Console.WriteLine(startTime.ToShortTimeString());
  startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(30);
}
```

Comment: Giving some explanations with your code would greatly help your answer to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you use TimeSpan (time instead of Time and Date in DateTime)

```
TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
TimeSpan beginTime = new TimeSpan(18, 00, 00);
TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(21, 00, 00);

for(TimeSpan tsLoop = beginTime; tsLoop < endTime; tsLoop = tsLoop.Add(interval))
{

}
```