# foreach day in month

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I loop through a date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847580/how-do-i-loop-through-a-date-range)

Is there a way to make a foreach loop for each day in a specific month?

thinking of something like

```
foreach (DateTime date in DateTime.DaysInMonth(2012, 1))
{
}
```

Comment: What you need to to with each day? Do you need a full date or just numeric value for each day?

Comment: I actually think it would be brilliant if DateTime did return an IEnumerable<DateTime> for a requested date range.

Comment: @sll I'm making a calendar where the whole year is visible, and where people would be able to make notes on single dates

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can write a helper method pretty easily:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> AllDatesInMonth(int year, int month)
{
    int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    for (int day = 1; day <= days; day++)
    {
         yield return new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }
}
```

Then call it with:

```
foreach (DateTime date in AllDatesInMonth(2012, 1))
```

This is probably overkill for something you're only doing *once*, but it's much nicer than using a `for` loop or something similar if you're doing this a lot. It makes your code say *just* what you want to achieve, rather than the mechanics for how you're doing it.

Comment: Even better replace the first two lines of this function with:   foreach(var day in Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))

Comment: I feel like this question just got Skeeted over.

Comment: You can go one step further if you are using linq by replacing all of the lines inside the function with this: 
return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)).Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day));

Comment: @Aston: Yup, absolutely.

Answer (score 25):

Try using a for loop instead.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month); i++)
{
  DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, i);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use Range:

```
Enumerable
    .Range(1, DateTime.DayInMonth(2012, 1)
    .Select(i => new DateTime(2012, 1, i)))
    .ToList() // ForEach is not a Linq to Sql method (thanks @Markus Jarderot)
    .ForEach(day => Console.Write(day));
```

Comment: Or one step further `Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DayInMonth(2012, 1)).Select(day => new DateTime(2012, 1, day))`

Comment: I don't get this working `Enumerable
  .Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(2012, 1))
  .Select(i => new DateTime(2012, 1, i))
  .ForEach(day => Console.Write(day));`. *Error CS1061: Type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.DateTime> does not contain a definition for ForEach and no extension method ForEach of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.DateTime> could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS1061)*

Comment: @testing, Probably, need `using System.Linq`

Comment: @Joe: I did this, but the error was still there. Perhaps the Xamarin Linq version is different from the Visual Studio one ...

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>.ForEach` is not an extension-method from LINQ. The method is provided in the (now old) [LINQ Extensions Library](https://linqlib.codeplex.com/). The easiest alternative in BCL would be to use `.ToList().ForEach(...)`

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with a simple loop:

```
DateTime first = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
for (DateTime current = first ; current.Month == first.Month ; current = current.AddDays(1)) {
}
```

Comment: I love making use of the often-neglected capability to use for loops with data types other than int.

Answer (score 5):

It is fairly easy to generate an enumeration of days.  Here is one way to do it

```
Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)).Select(day =>
    new DateTime(year, month, day))
```