# Month difference between 2 dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to calculate MONTH difference between one date column and today. Do we have any method in csharp like monthdiff or datediff to achieve this functionlaity? Issue with my code is if submission date year is different then it breaks.

```
bool isDateAccepted = ((SubmissionDate.Month - DateTime.Now.Month) < 6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always add 6 months to the submission date, and compare it to the current date.

```
bool isDateAccepted = (submissionDate.AddMonths(6) > DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Very elegant solution if the OP wants to take day of the month in to account.

Answer (score 3):

Don't directly compare the `Month` variables, as it will break when the month number "wraps" as you have noticed.

Instead, subtract the `DateTime` objects to get a `TimeSpan` then use *that* `TotalDays` property:

```
bool isDateAccepted = ((SubmissionDate - DateTime.Now).TotalDays < 6 * 30)
```

`TimeSpan` doesn't consider `Months`, so you'll have to define an average number of days in order to check the number for months passed.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? I believe this is a valid approach.

Comment: I did because it's flawed. Take 1-Mar-14, your method would tell the system dates from 1-Mar-14 through 28-Aug-14 are in the range. But one would expect that 29 to 31-Aug-2014 are within 6 months too. You could use 365/2f but that would also have similar errors.

Comment: @weston Fair enough, I agree that using the average is not an "ideal" solution (of course, that's mostly because our month system is just as flawed).

Comment: @weston btw, really liked your solution; thought it was really clever.

Answer (score 3):

You could calculate the total months and subtract them:

```
public int MonthDifference(Date a, Date b)
{
   int totalMonthsA = a.Year*12 + a.Month;
   int totalMonthsB = b.Year*12 + b.Month;
   return totalMonthsA - totalMonthsB;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a too late answer and as I checked no one answered about the exact fractions of the months like what we have in the `TimeSpan.TotalDays` for example.

for example what is the result of total months between `20-01-2021` and `20-03-2021`?
I guess it should be `2.0xx`, but if you considered Feb as 30 days, you'll get a different answer "`1.8xx` or something"

So I've done the calculation according to the days in each month between the selected dates.

- First I've got the list of days between the selected two dates as in [@mqp answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1847601/105445)
- then I grouped them by month and did the calculation

the code:

```
public static double GetTotalMonths(this DateTimeOffset firstDate, DateTimeOffset thru)
{
    var days = firstDate.EachDayTill(thru).ToList();
    return days.GroupBy(d => new {d.Month, d.Year,})
        .Sum(g => (g.Count() * 1.00) / (DateTime.DaysInMonth(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month) * 1.00));
}


public static IEnumerable<DateTimeOffset> EachDayTill(this DateTimeOffset from, DateTimeOffset thru)
{
    for (var day = new DateTimeOffset(from.Date, TimeSpan.Zero); day.Date <= thru.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
        yield return day;
}
```