# Iterate over each Day between StartDate and EndDate

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a `DateTime` StartDate and EndDate.

How can I, irrespective of times, iterate across each Day between those two?

> Example: StartDate is 7/20/2010 5:10:32 PM and EndDate is 7/29/2010
>   1:59:12 AM.

I want to be able to iterate across 7/20, 7/21, 7/22 .. 7/29.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533767/how-do-you-iterate-through-every-day-of-the-year

Answer (score 139, accepted):

```
for(DateTime date = StartDate; date.Date <= EndDate.Date; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    ...
}
```

The .Date is to make sure you have that last day, like in the example.

Comment: I think you want `date.Date <= EndDate.Date` so that you get the final day.

Comment: This goes into an infinite loop, the AddDays method doesn't change date, but returns a new DateTime instance. 

Use date = date.AddDays(1) instead.

Comment: @Dean: Thanks, saw your comment after change.

Comment: **+1** I didn't know you could use a for loop like this.

Comment: For some reason this just seems engenius to me.

Answer (score 14):

An alternative method that might be more reusable is to write an extension method on DateTime and return an IEnumerable.

For example, you can define a class:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable EachDay(this DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        // Remove time info from start date (we only care about day). 
        DateTime currentDay = new DateTime(start.Year, start.Month, start.Day);
        while (currentDay <= end)
        {
            yield return currentDay;
            currentDay = currentDay.AddDays(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the calling code you can do the following:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
DateTime end = start.AddDays(20);
foreach (var day in start.EachDay(end))
{
    ...
}
```

Another advantage to this approach is that it makes it trivial to add EachWeek, EachMonth etc. These will then all be accessible on DateTime.

Comment: You can remove time info from the date with DateTime.Date : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: why don't you do it type-safe? IEnumerable<DateTime>?

Answer (score 4):

You have to be careful about end-date. For example, in

> Example: StartDate is 7/20/2010 5:10:32 PM and EndDate is 7/29/2010 1:59:12 AM.
>   I want to be able to iterate across 7/20, 7/21, 7/22 .. 7/29.

`date < endDate` will not include 7/29 ever. When you add 1 day to 7/28 5:10 PM - it becomes 7/29 5:10 PM which is higher than 7/29 2 AM.

If that is not what you want then I'd say you do

```
for (DateTime date = start.Date; date <= end.Date; date += TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
{
     Console.WriteLine(date.ToString());
}
```

or something to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

The loops of @Yuriy Faktorovich, @healsjnr and @mho will all throw a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime`
exception if `EndDate == DateTime.MaxValue`.
To prevent this, add an extra check at the end of the loop

```
for(DateTime date = StartDate; date.Date <= EndDate.Date; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
   ...
   if (date.Date == DateTime.MaxValue.Date)
   {
       break;
   }
}
```

(I would have posted this as a comment to @Yuriy Faktorovich's answer, but I lack reputation)

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime endDate = date.AddDays(10);

while (date < endDate)
{
  Console.WriteLine(date);
  date = date.AddDays(1);
}
```