# For Each statement for DayOfWeek Enum

Tags: c#, datetime, foreach

I have two DateTime values called `StartDate` and `EndDate`. by default they only span the period of a week, however, the user can expand them farther.

I'm trying to write a HTML table that will insert rows foreach day in that span of time.

For example:

```
foreach DayOfWeek in (StartDate thru EndDate)<br/>
OUTPUT
 <tr>
  <th>[DAYOFWEEK]</th>
 </tr>
```

Comment: is this using MVC razor? or is this just plain HTML/Javascript?

Comment: See [C#: Iterate over each Day between StartDate and EndDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359768/c-iterate-over-each-day-between-startdate-and-enddate)

Comment: Sooo... exactly what is the problem? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not tested, but should work.

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 20);
var endDate = new DateTime(2014, 3, 10);

var days = (endDate - startDate).TotalDays;

Console.WriteLine("<tr>");
for(int i = 0; i <= days; i++)
{
   var theDate = startDate.AddDays(i);
   Console.WriteLine("<th>{0}</th>", theDate.DayOfWeek);
}
Console.WriteLine("</tr>");
```

**Update**

Just got inspired to write this little helper

```
public static class DateTimeHelper
{
    public static void ForEach(DateTime from, DateTime to, Action<DateTime> action)
    {
        if (to < from)
            for (DateTime date = from; date.Date >= to.Date; date = date.AddDays(-1))
                action.Invoke(date);
        else
            for (DateTime date = from; date.Date <= to.Date; date = date.AddDays(1))
                action.Invoke(date);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
DateTimeHelper.ForEach(startDate, endDate, date =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(date);
});
```

**Update2**: fixed ForEach support for EndDate > StartDate

Comment: Console.WriteLine will not write, Any idea to get it rendered, <text> tag is also not working, any guess ?

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta - Console WriteLine was just an example. How to output text depends on the technology you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 08, 12);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 08, 24);


    for (DateTime d = start; d < end; d = d.AddDays(1))
    {
        @(d.ToString()) <br/>
    }
}
```