# Adding every day from TimeDate.ElaspedDays to a list

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I'm new to using DateTime but I'm wondering if it is able to add every single day between two points to a list dynamically.

For example, my code looks like this:

```
{
  startTime = new DateTime(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
  endTime = new DateTime(endYear, endMonth, endDay);        
  TimeSpan elapsed = endTime.Subtract(startTime);               
  startString = startDay.ToString();
  elapsedString = elapsed.TotalDays.ToString();
}
```

Through this I can return the total amount of days between two points. However, `elapsed.TotalDays.ToString();` only returns the total amount of days between two points. What I'm wondering is if it is possible to return every single day between two points and place it into a list?

Comment: Does between mean including start and end days?

Comment: Good information, you should probably put that in your main post body.   My latest edits reflect the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try, it should work:

```
int totalDays = endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalDays as int;
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>(totalDays + 1); // using this constructor will make filling in the list more performant

dates.Add(startTime); // since you mentionned start and end should be included

for (var i = 1; i < totalDays; i++)
{
    dates.Add(startTime.AddDays(i));
}

dates.Add(endTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `Enumerable.Range`

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

var totalDays = (int)endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalDays;
var days = Enumerable.Range(0, totalDays)
                     .Select(n => startTime.AddDays(n))
                     .ToList();
```

Both start and enddates are included in the `days` list.  Start by setting the range to start at zero, end by leaving `n` alone.

Answer (score 3):

i think you can iterate using for

```
list<int>Dates = new List<int>();

for(DateTime date = StartDate; date.Date <= EndDate.Date; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
  Dates.Add(date.Date);
}
```

Comment: Never thought of using `for` with `DateTime`. :)

Comment: being honest i refered stackoverflow link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359768/iterate-over-each-day-between-startdate-and-enddate> so credit for him