# Iterate through all days from a given year

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to get a list of days `List<string>` from a given year in the following format: `dd.MM.yyyy`

```
public List<string> GetDays(int year)
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();

    foreach-day-in-year // TO DO iterate days from given year
    {
       string day="";

       // TO DO  iterate all days

       lst.Add(day);
    }       

    return lst;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/533778/2654498

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public IList<string> GetDays(int year)
    {
        var days = new List<string>();
        var start = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);

        while (start.Year == year)
        {
            days.Add(start.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
            start = start.AddDays(1);
        }

        return days;
    }
```